# Number Plate Recognition with Java and OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv

I know this topic has come up a lot on this site, but my needs are a bit different than what I've come across so far.

Before I start, I just want to say that at no point do I want any code handed to me, as this is part of my final year project for my degree. I'm just looking for a bit of dialog and input.

So, I'm writing an app for android, and one part of it is to take a picture of a number plate and process it. Now, for this app, we are taking an image up close, as seen in the below picture(taken from google, but still the same)
[image]

Now as you can see, the number plate has quite a lot of detail which needs to be ignored. I'm finding that an up close image is becoming harder to process than the far away one because we see far more detail that we would rather ignore.

I'm aware of the usual steps in doing number plate processing, here is a quick mock up i did:
[image]

What I'm really looking for is some advice on how to get rid of the unwanted details as described above. And as I said, no code handouts please.

Comment: The binary has nice big characters on it. I would use `findContours()` on that one. Then I'd play around with sorting through the contours by size and proximity to each other to figure out which contours are your characters. Then remove everything that isn't your characters and run the edge detection or whatever optical character recognition thing you're using. Just curious: what's the point of doing the "Histogram EQ"?

Comment: In the picture above, it does pretty much nothing, but in some images where the plate is dirty it helps a bit to make the characters a lot more obvious. But really it's just research at the moment. I'll have a look in to your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Not clear what do you want at the end? Do you want a program to give you a plate number? Like: `131-D-92`?

Comment: Yes. What I'm currently trying to do is remove any detail that isn't needed. Ideally I'll end up with a black image with 131-D-92 in white. 

But as I said, having the image taken so close is causing unwanted details to remain even after heavy processing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach.

- extract square region of the plate like your `main image`. Convert the image to some standard size
- no need for bluring/ histogram EQ. Just do a greyscale, and binarization
- run a [sliding window](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs543/sp2011/lectures/Lecture%2019%20-%20Sliding%20Window%20Detection%20-%20Vision_Spring2011.pdf) on your image. You know approximate size of the number (looks like 70% of the hight of the plate), so you already know the height of the sliding window.
- for each selected window you check whether it is a digit or a number.

This gives you the plate number. Now you can easily draw it (if you want).

Answer (score 0):

How robust are you looking to make this app?  are you happy if it will only work on nice clean plates?  my guess that because it is for a school project you can get away with only using nice plates.

In this case, I would focus on finding your anchor points that always exist...like the mainly solid inner rectangle(that contains the numbers and some upper text) in your 'binarization' pic. Another anchor could be the "IRL" text...do a template matching process to find that to confirm that your rectangle is correct.

Also, if you can confirm you have the correct rectangle, you can transform it so that it is perfectly square and scaled to the correct size.  Then chop it up into its digits...either by fixed sized slices or by finding contours inside and simply chopping by their min/max x coordinates.

See here http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html
for example of the warping.  Resizing is easy so you don't need an example.  You don't want code so you'll need to work the math out for your warping. The hint would be that you'll have a trapezoid that you want to convert to a rectangle. (it'll only be slightly trapezoidal when photo is taken at an angle...you may be able to get away with no warping and just a resize as a start).

Be careful of a sliding window as not all digits are the same width. Best to separate them by contours, snag the crop and perform some basic heuristics and comparisons to determine the digit/letter value.

If you're dealing with all plates, clean and messy, from various countries...I'd opt for a pipeline with some opencv, then a conv-net to get your region or interest, then some fancy google street numbers sort of process to read the number/digits(probably a sliding windows approach).